# Ninject: No Matching bindings are available

Tags: ninject, mvvm-light

I am facing the same issue that many have faced before: the dreaded no matching binding.

Here is my registration logic

```
    static Bootstrapper()
    {
        Container = new StandardKernel();

        var dialogService = new DialogService();
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow(Messenger.Default, dialogService);
        dialogService.Intialize(mainWindow.DialogContainer);

        Container.Bind<MainWindow>().ToConstant(mainWindow);
        Container.Bind<IDialogService>().ToConstant(dialogService);
        Container.Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod((ctx) => LogManager.GetLogger("Main"));
        Container.Bind<IMessenger>().ToConstant(Messenger.Default);
        Container.Bind<IEntityService>().To<EntityService>();
        Container.Bind<EntityMasterDetailViewModel>().To<EntityMasterDetailViewModel>().InSingletonScope();
        Container.Bind<MainViewModel>().To<MainViewModel>().InSingletonScope();
    }
```

And the issue is raised when resolving EntityMasterDetailViewModel

```
    public EntityMasterDetailViewModel(
        IDialogService dialog,
        IEntityService service)
    {
        _service = service;
        _dialog = dialog;
    }
```

That is the only constructor on that class. I also eliminated the possibility of having multiple container(using readonly static).

I can't figure out what is wrong with the registration of the class. All of its dependency have been defined in the container.

Right now I would get the following error:

```
  Error activating IDialogService
  No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
  Activation path:
  2) Injection of dependency IDialogService into parameter dialog of 
  constructor of type EntityMasterDetailViewModel
  1) Request for EntityMasterDetailViewModel
```

Can anyone spot anything wrong?

Cheers,

**EDIT 1**

I can resolve both dependencies: `Container.Get<IDialogService>()` and `Container.Get<IEntityService>()` both returns the correct instance. So it must be the way I register EntityMasterDetailViewModel. I tried a few alternatives but none worked:

```
     Container.Bind<EntityMasterDetailViewModel>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
     Container.Bind<EntityMasterDetailViewModel>().ToMethod(_ => Container.Get<Entity<asterDetailViewModel>()).InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: have you tried `Get<EntityMasterDetailViewModel>()` at the end of the static bootstrapper method? Did you check whether there's any other place in your code where you create a kernel (`new StandardKernel();`)?

Comment: could it be that you have several `IDialogService` and that you are referencing different ones in BootStrapper and  `EntityMasterDetailViewModel` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments, they gave me a hint on what went wrong: I was using static constructor incorrectly, thus the kernel was not initialized properly while calls to Get<> were issued.

Really what I wanted to implement was a singleton. So I switched things around for the correct pattern. This time, all the registrations/bindings happened before the first call to Get<>(); and I no longer get the exception/error.